# Restructure Eloquent Collection for better API access

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a REST API based on Elequent ORM.
My query returns something like this when requesting a single object:

```
$data = $this->select('objects.*')->where('id', '=', $id)->get();
```

The collection:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3414,
        "type": 3,
        "title": "Title",
        "shorttext": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.",
        "spacetext": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua."

    }
]
```

So i would like to change the structure the API returns into something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3414,
        "type": 3,
        "text" {
            "title": "Title",
            "shorttext": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.",
            "spacetext": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua."
        }

    }
]
```

In that ways the structure is a bit more transparent for the access user. This should of course work also when requesting not only a single object via GET but also a list of objects.

I tried using eloquent mapping collections via `mapToGroups()` but i got nowhere.

Before using Eloquent i was using Medoo. There i just had to enter a schema array like this and everything was done:

```
$this->schema = [
        'id', 
        'type',
        'text' => [
            'title',
            'shorttext',
            'spacetext',
            'description'
        ],
        'prices' => [
            'baseprice',
            '...
```

Is there a good way of achieving this with eloquent?

Comment: Why not map()? Following [basic example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-map): `$item->text = new \stdClass();$item->text->title = $item->title;unset($item->$title);/* plus other properties the same way */`. Maybe.

Comment: Divide your object table into two tables, then do a one to one relationship. At least is the easiest way to do it. Another is to restructure your array using map()

Comment: I'm trying using map but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what version of Laravel you are using. For older versions (5.4 and below) of Laravel there is a great simple package called [Fractal](https://fractal.thephpleague.com/resources/) that will help achieve what you are looking for.

> Fractal provides a presentation and transformation layer for complex
>   data output, the like found in RESTful APIs, and works really well
>   with JSON.

Here is a sample of that code a work:

```
<?php namespace App\Transformer;

use Acme\Model\Book;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

class BookTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    /**
     * List of resources possible to include
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $availableIncludes = [
        'author'
    ];

    /**
     * Turn this item object into a generic array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function transform(Book $book)
    {
        return [
            'id'    => (int) $book->id,
            'title' => $book->title,
            'year'    => (int) $book->yr,
            'links'   => [
                [
                    'rel' => 'self',
                    'uri' => '/books/'.$book->id,
                ]
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Include Author
     *
     * @return \League\Fractal\Resource\Item
     */
    public function includeAuthor(Book $book)
    {
        $author = $book->author;

        return $this->item($author, new AuthorTransformer);
    }
}
```

In newer versions ([5.5+](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/releases)) you can use the [Eloquent Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources) concept.

> A resource class represents a single model that
>   needs to be transformed into a JSON structure. For example, here is a
>   simple resource class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class SampleModel extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'type' => $this->type,
            'text' => [
                'title' => $this->title,
                'short_text' => $this->short_text,
            ],
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting.

Comment: That's it. I will use fractal, because including all Illuminate\Http dependencies is a bit much in this case.

Comment: @Mike glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$remove = ["title", "shorttext", "spacetext", "description"];
$data->map(function($a) use($remove){
    foreach ($remove as $value) {
        $a["text"][$value] = $a[$value];
        unset($a[$value]);
    }
    return $a;
});
```

Comment: If i test this: `$data = $data->map(function ($item, $key) { return $item+1;   });`i get this result `[2]`

Comment: No but i'm trying first to modify every value to see if i can access it. If that works i can go on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle this with adding an extra `attribute` in your `model`. So your `model` should look like:

e.g.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Objects extends Model {

    protected $appends = ['text']; 

    public function getTextAttribute(){
        return array("shorttext" => $this->shorttext, "spacetext" => $this->spacetext, "description" => $this->description);
    }
}
```

It will give you the desired result.

But you will find all three columns also in side the JSON or Array. So need to set it to hidden if they are not required using `$hidden`

e.g.

```
protected $hidden = ['shorttext', 'spacetext', 'description' ];  // add this line in your model if you want to hide these columns in response json or array.
```

Remember, you can still access these properties if you just find or get the model. It will only be set to `hidden when converted to JSON or Array` Or while returning in response. 
If you want to show them then just use `setVisible()` method.

e.g.

```
//Inside controller
$records = Objects->where('somekey', 'somevalue')->get() ; 
$records->setVisible(['shorttext', 'spacetext', 'description']);
```

Comment: That's also an interesting way of doing it. But i think that using fractal is a bit better organised for future changes, don't you think?